# Twitter Integration Issue with the authorization

Tags: android, twitter, authorization

I have done a lot of Googling and integrated Twitter in my App. But I am stuck at one point. In all the other example I found and created, I am facing the same issue.

I am provided with a 7-digit number and told that I have to return to the Application I created at the http://dev.twitter.com and then enter the provided pin to complete the authorization process.

Without this I am not able to Tweet from my App on Twitter. Now I have tried to go to the Application in the Twitter developer account but I couldn't find the place where I can place the number.

[image]

Comment: Please see below link for complete example of twitter integration in android application with source code, it will solve your problem. [Twitter Integration in Android Application](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android.html)

Comment: I still face the Same problem of getting a number to authorize the Application.

Comment: After note above information then please tell me so i can remove that.

Comment: I didn't got what you asked for, Sorry. Can you make it clear.

Comment: @IGP_ I am not getting the Issue with your Cousumer Key and Secret Key. I think I am making some mistake in App Creation. I have just replaced your data with mine and it's working.

Comment: Can You tell me How to attach an Image here So that I can show you my Data of created app. on dev.twitter.com

Comment: First create new app on twitter developer account and if you have any issue regarding that then tell me.

Comment: You can not attach image in comment section, please attach your image in your question.

Comment: I have accepted your answer and I am not able to attach the image in the question.

Comment: Access level  Read, write, and direct messages 
About the application permission model
Consumer key 0i6FSe3LhDCAMz3WSnRw
Consumer secret qthJwFsI8lK26nBTFJl1tgWV3rtsiaulT7Bj1M9Lw
Request token URL https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
Authorize URL https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
Access token URL https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
Callback URL None
Your access token

Access token 263580867-UyNwuDprrRnY4iwBvkVcOYqMwNImS6yGbIrYYHhB
Access token secret 6MJfC9Kz269NtL7pmNdZWi2P8ruVBR9bq1ZvrZ45QU
Access level Read-only

Comment: I am stuck now as I am just replacing your credentials and it's working fine and not for any of mine. The above is the info. I have for my created App.

Comment: Post your images on any other server and post links here.

Comment: http://darshanbarot.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/52/ I get when I click the Login Button and
http://darshanbarot.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/77/ is the credentials Image

Comment: Your problem is solved or not?

Comment: I have posted the links of the server where I have posted the Images, please go through them if You can and see where I am stuck.

My problem is not solved yet, And thanks so much for your cooperation IGP, I appereciate

Comment: darshanbarot.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/52 I get when I click the Login Button and darshanbarot.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/77 is the credentials Image – Here are they

Comment: Tomorrow i will make one application for you on twitter developer account and give you consumer_key, consumer_secret and callback_url and if possible please go to my profile and take my email id from there and mail me your email address so i can send you complete detail on your mail id.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am done finely now.

Comment: Su vaat 6e David, twitter upar kam karo 6o....

Comment: how did you resolve it.can you please tell me what to change here i have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem while I did provide empty Callback url. You need to make call back url in http://dev.twitter.com/apps/xyz  account and make callback url. Use that Call back url while Login